# How to check if a ClaimsIdentity is already Signed In

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

i'm developing a webapp with VS2013 and MVC5.

I'm logging in user with this code:

```
private void Authenticate(Agente agente)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, agente.Id.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim("Nome", agente.Nome));
        claims.Add(new Claim("Cognome", agente.Cognome));
        claims.Add(new Claim("Username", agente.Username));
        claims.Add(new Claim("Id", agente.Id.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim("Cmtt", agente.Cmtt.ToString()));

        claims.Add(new Claim("LivelloAgente",agente.Ruolo.LivelloAgente.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim("LivelloSupv", agente.Ruolo.LivelloSupv.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim("LivelloAdmin", agente.Ruolo.LivelloAdmin.ToString()));

        ClaimsIdentity claimsId = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(claimsId);

    }
```

When i call Authenticate(Agente agente) i've just checked username and password in my DB.

I would like to check if the same pair (username/password) is already logged in without store "logged" in DB.

I think that if the same ClaimsIdentity is already "stored" somewhere server-side, that user is already logged from somewhere else.But ClaimsIdentity is only stored in the cookie , right?

So, how to check if that user is already logged from another place?

Thank you,
Fulvio